# Is there a way to configure sonar-maven-plugin to store reports via REST API

Tags: postgresql, maven, sonarqube

We are using the maven plugin org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.sonar-maven-plugin to store our reports to our sonar qube instance. For company reasons our CI server is in a different network zone then this instance and postgres default port is closed. I wonder if there is an option to store the reports in a different way then having them written directly to database via jdbc, as opening ports is a tedious task here ;)

Furthermore, we also have some older pieces of software that need to be analyzed with a local sonar runner instance and the same question applies here (so if there is another way to store the reports)

Comment: Which version of sonarqube are you using ? Since 5.2 there are no connections between scanner and database anymore so you should probably upgrade (Latest LTS is 5.6 anyway).

Comment: Unforturnatelly we are at 5.1...

Comment: Is there another option, as I already know that it will be a hazzle to "force" the guys running the instance right now to upgrade

Comment: Nope, no other option. That's just how old versions of SonarQube were designed. And your use-case is precisely why later versions were improved to [break free](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+and+Integration) from this (as explained by @benzonico).

Comment: Arguments you could use is that LTS is 5.6 so you are using an obsolete version and it is way more secure to avoid the connection to DB (and opening a port).

Comment: Ok, then let's see what happens. I'll try to convince them to move on and get rid of this "write reports directly to DB feature". Your perfectly right, they should be afraid by the potential security threads they offer by that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 5.2 there is no connection to the database from the scanners. So the easiest/safest course of action here should be to upgrade to the latest LTS (at time of writing 5.6 )